# SQL триггеры. Таблицы inserted не существует

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, триггер

Здравствуйте, уважаемые специалисты, пишу свой самый первый sql триггер, возникли трудности, прошу помощи. Действия триггера такие: при добавлении новой строки в таблицу "questions2", он создает новую строку в другой таблице "cnt_answ" с таким же id, вот код:

```
INSERT INTO cnt_answ VALUES ((SELECT id FROM inserted),0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но при добавлении записи в таблицу questions2 выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
#1146 - Таблица 'salam89q_db_utf.inserted' не существует
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она же вроде виртуальная, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Какой диалект? MySQL?

Comment: прочитайте документацию на язык MySQL и его триггера. таблица inserted доступна только в MS SQL Server, а это совершенно другая СУБД

Comment: @Mike спасибо, а в MySQL получить данные новой строки как-нибудь можно?

Comment: @Zufir MySQL:5.7.20-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В триггере доступны поля текущей записи через префиксы `NEW` для триггеров INSERT, UPDATE и с префиксом `OLD` для триггеров UPDATE, DELETE. Более того, переменные `NEW` в BEFORE триггерах можно модифицировать

```
INSERT INTO cnt_answ VALUES (NEW.id, 0)
```

Да и настоятельно не рекомендуется в INSERT опускать список полей. Перечислите их явно, даже если их десяток. Потому, что завтра поля и их порядок может быть совершенно другим

```
INSERT INTO cnt_answ(quest_id, cnt) VALUES (NEW.id, 0)
```

Comment: `for each row` ещё стоит описать. И ссылку https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: @Zufir без `for each row` в MySQL триггеров не бывает и PhpMyAdmin ее сам добавит. Нужно только в редакторе включить просмотр DDL

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо, заработало. очень выручил.

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов Настоятельно не рекомендуется в `INSERT` опускать список полей. Перечислите их явно, даже если их десяток